# iText add new page

Tags: java, rtf, itext

How can you add a new page to an iText document? `document.newPage();` doesn't seem to work.

I am using iText with RTF support from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrtf/

Part of my code:

```
Font titleFont = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD);
document.add(new Paragraph("Title1", titleFont));

Table table = new Table(4);
table.setBorderWidth(0);

// Filling table

document.add(table);

document.newPage();

document.add(new Paragraph("Title2", titleFont));

Table table = new Table(4);
table.setBorderWidth(0);

// Filling table

document.add(table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using a wrong RTF reader, the breakline was there, the reader just didn't render it.

Answer (score 10):

***Edit***: Re your updated question with code, neither of the below seems to apply. Leaving in case they help someone else out.

Calling [`newPage`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfDocument.html#newPage()) tells iText to place subsequent objects on a new page. The new page will only actually get created when you place the next object (at least, that's what it does for me). Also, `newPage` only creates a new page if the current page is not blank; otherwise, it's ignored; you can use [`setPageBlank(false)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfDocument.html#setPageEmpty(boolean)) to overcome that.

Comment: Added some example code, I am adding new Elements after newPage is called.

Comment: @MrThys: V. strange. I have code that looks quite similar and works. Sorry not to have another idea for you, good luck with it.

Comment: @MyThys: Not really, it's too spread out, but it basically comes down to adding some objects (images or text), calling `newPage`, and adding more objects (images or text).

Comment: Additional : After called `newPage()`,Define as `table= new PdfPTable(4)`  and then add 3 cell into `table`.The last page of three cells is disappeared.In this case, add `4 or 4*n` cells seems worked well.

Answer (score 0):

RTF is no longer supported by iText, as the main author of the relevant code moved on to other projects... or was transformed into a frog... or something.  Anyway, I recommend you seek a new RTF library, or perhaps start maintaining it yourself?

At any rate, the Source Is Available, and I suspect the RTFDocument/RTFWriter ignores newPage().  Nope.  RtfWriter2.java:

```
/**
 * Adds a page break
 *
 * @return <code>false</code>
 */
public boolean newPage() {
    rtfDoc.add(new RtfNewPage(rtfDoc));
    return true;
}
```

which should just write "//page" into the output file.  Is it there?

Comment: Hi Mark, I/m facing same issue with pdfContentbByte.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737501/how-to-get-new-page-in-itext  .  Any suggestion?