# Insert images in different pdf pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to set a list of images in a PDF document using iText with Java, i could just insert some of them in the first page but i don't know how to jump to the next pages in order to put the rest of my pictures

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    Image myImg = Image.getInstance("/home/code/img"+i+".png");
    imgPaper.setAbsolutePosition(50, 728-(y*58)); 
    document.add(myImg);
    y++;
}
```

Comment: Appears to be a re-hashed version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284691/itext-add-new-page

Comment: i have already another pages, i just want how to jump to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP clarified his question in a comment

> i have already another pages, i just want how to jump to them

You seem to be creating a new document using a `PdfWriter`. That class is designed to create a pdf one page after the other. As soon as you start a new page, all former ones are written to file.

Thus, in this process **you cannot jump to arbitrary pages.** You have to add all information for a page while it is the current one.

If, after creating a multi page document, you need to manipulate the content of its pages, first close the document (finishing it), read it into a `PdfReader`, and apply a `PdfStamper` which allows you to manipulate arbitrary pages of an existing PDF.

Alternatively, especially if your images constitute something like a water mark or header/footer Logos, consider using page events in your pdf creation process with the `PdfWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a new line to your document

```
document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
```

link for info:

[How to insert blank lines in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158336/how-to-insert-blank-lines-in-pdf-using-itext)

Comment: i guess you haven't understand my question, i am asking about inserting images in different pages.. not to leave a space between them.