# How to get new page in iText

Tags: java, itext

Its bit problmatic to go for new page with `pdfContentByte`.I'm using below code to put data after first page to next page but unfortunately `iText` is not generating new page.

```
//step1
    itextDocument = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 30, 65);
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(itextDocument, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    itextDocument.open();
    writer.setPageEmpty(true);
    itextDocument.newPage();


    // step 2 == design and set the postions


    // Measuring a String in Helvetica
    Font font = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10);
    BaseFont romanFont = font.getCalculatedBaseFont(false);


    // Drawing lines to see where the text is added
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    canvas.saveState();




     canvas.stroke();
        canvas.restoreState();
        // Adding text with PdfContentByte.showTextAligned()
        canvas.beginText();
        canvas.setFontAndSize(romanFont, 10);

        //===================  get data from xml and put in pdf 
        createPDF(xmlDoc, canvas);



        createPDF(xmlDoc, canvas){
             for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
                contentByte.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "sample value", flotX, flotY, 0); 
             }
         }

    static int flotX = 50;
    static int flotY = 800;
```

how can I generate new page? Any suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't you use **writer.setPageEmpty(false);** instead?

Comment: Make that an answer @mkl ;-)

Comment: Yes I have used  writer.setPageEmpty(true) before itextDocument.newPage() but still no luck.You can see the code.

Comment: You use **true** - but **false** is what you need.

Comment: but false is creating blank page not new page with exceeded data.

Comment: But your code does not add any data.

Comment: If I understand you correctly now, you want data which doesn't fit on the first page to be drawn on the second one. As you chose to layout data yourself, you have to do that manually, at least to some degree. To help you with that, we'd need that **createPDF** method.

Comment: createPDF(xmlDoc, canvas) . I'm using this method to add data in this  in for loop by contentByte.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, textValue, flotX, flotY, 0);

Comment: please check the updated code and suggest me if there is any possible solution. X,Y values are changing dynamically to add text in pdf but could add text after end of pdf as new page is not creating.

Comment: I'll take a look, but you should only accept an answer if you consider your question answered, at least to some degree..

Comment: I'm a bit mystified. Your **createPDF** method draws the same text at the same position 300 times. What's the sense of that? Probably You had better explain what you try to do because your code simply does not make any sense.

Comment: @mkl : As i mentioned in my prev comment that the position of X,Y changing dynamically and printing text line by line in first page of pdf, and after completion first page second page is not occurring while data is still there which should be print.

Comment: Ok. It looks like you assume the content of the whole PDF is drawn on the same canvas and pages are different sections of it. This is wrong, each page has its own canvas. But one can emulate a single canvas approach. I extended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### On the use of **writer.setPageEmpty**

You use

```
writer.setPageEmpty(true);
```

You should use

```
writer.setPageEmpty(false);
```

instead to indicate that the current page shall not be considered empty. As long as it is considered empty, newPage won't change anything.

### Adding content to multiple pages manually

If you really want to create PDF content using low level methods (i.e. directly positioning text on a `PdfContentByte` canvas instead of leaving the layouting to iText), you have to realize that each page has its own content canvas of which a rectangle (the crop box defaulting to the media box) is displayed while the rest remains hidden.

The `PdfContentByte` returned by `writer.getDirectContent` is automatically switched when a new page is started.

Thus, for content spread across pages, you have to call `itextDocument.newPage` exactly when you want to get to the next page, and then start filling the crop box again.

Along the lines of your sample code lines:

```
    Document itextDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 30, 65);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(itextDocument, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    itextDocument.open();

    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    BaseFont romanFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    // first page content
    canvas.setFontAndSize(romanFont, 10);
    canvas.beginText();
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 1 on page 1", 50, 800, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 2 on page 1", 50, 785, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 3 on page 1", 50, 770, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 755, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 740, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 725, 0);
    canvas.setFontAndSize(romanFont, 800);
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "1", 0, 100, 0); 
    canvas.endText();

    itextDocument.newPage();

    // first page content
    canvas.setFontAndSize(romanFont, 10);
    canvas.beginText();
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 1 on page 2", 50, 800, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 2 on page 2", 50, 785, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Line 3 on page 2", 50, 770, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 755, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 740, 0); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "................", 50, 725, 0); 
    canvas.setFontAndSize(romanFont, 800);
    canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "2", 0, 100, 0); 
    canvas.endText();

    itextDocument.close();
```

This produces these two pages:

[image]

Alternatively you could also create an independent, larger `PdfTemplate` (derived from `PdfContentByte`), draw all your content on it, and then show sections of it on different pages:

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("big-panel.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), 3 * PageSize.A4.getHeight());

    // draw all your content on tp

    cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, -2 * PageSize.A4.getHeight());
    document.newPage();
    cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, -PageSize.A4.getHeight());
    document.newPage();
    cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);
    document.newPage();
    cb.addTemplate(tp, 0.3333f, 0, 0, 0.3333f, PageSize.A4.getWidth() / 3, 0);
    document.close();
```

Comment: please suggest the use of panel.addNotify();
    panel.validate();

Comment: *please suggest the use of panel.addNotify(); panel.validate();* - sorry, that was a copy&paste error: The original sample I c&p'ed the code from filled `tp` from a Swing panel.

Comment: Hi mkl: when I'm trying to print this pdf, this showing info that 'an error exist on this page.Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact to the person who created the PDF document....'  . I did not insert any image in pdf also I'm using custom fonts like Arial of microsoft. Any Idea how can get out from this....really stuck in the issue. Please provide the suggestion.

Comment: *when I'm trying to print this pdf* - which *this* pdf? My answer presented two alternative approaches. Furthermore, I just executed the test routines with the code above once again and tried printing them... no problem occurred. Thus, you do something differently. Please explain what you did differently and how.

Comment: I have set the total number of copies 2 in my code by default preview printing 2 copies of pdf but when I go Print->properties->paper/finishing->paper source-->tray->tray1  then the total number of copies set to 1 from 2.  Is it possible to set copies value 2 when we select the tray from preview in itext ? I'm using Adobe Reader XI.  If you can share your contact then we can discuss about it in detail.

Comment: That to me seems a new question altogether.

Comment: I have asked a question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673548/itext-pdf-viewer-preferences-changing-dynamically

Comment: Ok, I just saw it. I'm not too deep into Adobe software details, so I'm hardly of help there.